# ARC Memory release doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

Hi all I read many example of memory deallocation using ARC,
they said that if you set the pointer to nill ARC will deallocate it for you,
also some tutorials have explained the thing very well but in my program it
still doesn't work....

the test consists of these lines:

```
while(1)
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"]];
    NSString *tmp =[formatter stringFromDate:now];
    lol = [tmp copy];
    tmp = nil;
    now = nil;
    formatter = nil;
    lol = nil;
}
```

it still grow in memory size...
Help me... maybe for do thi thngs i must to turn off ARC...

Comment: How do you know that the memory is growing?

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing, and more specifically, what leads you to believe that THIS block of code is where the leak is?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arc can autorelease data so in  a tight loop (you say you use while) the runloop isn't advanced and the autoreleasepool not drained.

put an explicit @autoreleasepool inside your loop

Comment: thanks it works ;), but what to do if i have two threads and an array of classes to pass between them? how i release the classes?

Comment: the objects get released if there really is no thread accessing them anymore

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you're trying to do with that code but it will help you if you'll wrap everything inside an @autorelease block like this:

```
@autorelease {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"]];
    NSString *tmp =[formatter stringFromDate:now];
    lol = [tmp copy];
    tmp = nil;
    now = nil;
    formatter = nil;
    lol = nil;
}
```

Comment: for me @autoreleae doesn't exist...

Comment: Well, you've spelled it wrong, it's `@autorelease`, not `@autoreleae`.